# Digital Certificate missing in IE7 and IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-7

I am using windows xp(x86) with IE7. I have downloaded a new digital certificate to access one secure webside. I have sucessfully installed the certificate. When i check the IE properties, the digial certificate is available there. But when i access the secure website the IE is prompting me to choose a certificate, but the prompt window is faded out and there is no cerfiticate to choose. . i upgraded the IE7 to IE8. but the prompt window is not appearing. please advice

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you installed your cert into the right cert store? (I'm no expert of this, try googling like 'windows certificate store'. There are more of such stores, each for different purpose.)

Comment: Yes. i can see the certificate under "content-> Certificates-> Personal".